# Reducing brightness of large areas containing bright colours

Tags: xorg, compiz, display, effects, compositing

I do most of my work in either a terminal or a web browser.  I prefer my terminals to use bright colours on dark.  I would really prefer that web pages tended to look this way as well, but that's not under my control.  The problem is that when I switch from a light-on-dark terminal to a dark-on-light web page (like this one), my eyes have to adjust to the overall rise in screen brightness.  Apparently this is bad for your eyes, in addition to being painful and annoying.

It would seem to be possible for some layer of the interface to adjust the displayed colours for parts of the screen, or perhaps for particular windows, to reduce the brightness of the brighter areas of the screen.  Can this be done, possibly with a Compiz extension?

Comment: I have problems with bright areas of the screen too.  For a while I tried what you're going for, but now I just go with dimming the screen and keeping a light (but not white--one computer is pastel yellow, another pastel pink) terminal background.  If I'm in a well-lit room, I can even turn the backlight off and still see it (saves battery life)

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyways or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reasons why you want it open. Regards

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> will toggle your browser to Negative so it looks surprisingly like a terminal

[image: Negative askubuntu]

Hope this helps

Comment: Somewhat helpful, but then I'll still have this problem with pages that use light-on-dark colouring, and with ones that don't but which contain dark images (like this page as of your post).